# Opening Google App Engine in a Python script

Tags: python, google-app-engine, subprocess, popen

I'm fairly new to programming and decided to setup a simple python script that would open all the applications I use for webapp development. The code I am using is (for GAE):

```
google_appengine = r'C:\Applications\google_app_engine\launcher\GoogleAppEngineLauncher.exe'
subprocess.Popen(google_appengine)
```

This works fine for the other programs I am opening, but I am unable to run any applications within App Engine after I have opened it this way. I get the following error in my App Engine log file:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "threading.pyc", line 486, in __bootstrap_inner
File "launcher\taskthread.pyc", line 65, in run
File "subprocess.pyc", line 587, in __init__
File "subprocess.pyc", line 700, in _get_handles
File "subprocess.pyc", line 745, in _make_inheritable
WindowsError: [Error 6] The handle is invalid
```

I'm guessing it is the way subprocess.Popen() works, but I haven't been able to find any alternatives. I'm running Windows 7 if that makes a difference. Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to manage the local dev_appserver, this is the wrong approach.

the best way to do this is clone the sdk repository ([https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/checkout)) directly to your drive and then add that path to your environment PYTHONPATH variable.

here's a link to a script template i created & often use to manage startup & killing of the dev_appserver process: https://gist.github.com/4514647

i'm not too familiar with managing a python environment on Windows, so you'd have to take my notes on a highlevel and research the specific implementation for that platform.